# ¿porque background-size: cover no esta funcionando al renderizar con React?

Tags: css, reactjs

Estoy intentando usar una imagen como fondo de mi div pero quiero un width del 100% y en mis estilos dice `background-size: cover` pero aun asi no funciona.

```js
render() { 
        
        return ( 
            <div className = "page-header header-filter bg-image">
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} >
                    {this.renderInput("username", "Username")}
                    {this.renderInput("password", "Password", "password")}
                    {this.renderInput("name", "Name")}
                    {this.renderButton("Register")}
                </form>
            </div>
         );
    }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.bg-image {
  background-image: url('https://github.com/Ceci007/images/blob/master/img-vidly/avengers.jpg?raw=true'); 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-position: center;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define como altura 100% (height: 100%;), esto sera necesario para que se vea en toda la pantalla:

```
.bg-image {
  background-image: url('https://github.com/Ceci007/images/blob/master/img-vidly/avengers.jpg?raw=true'); 
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 

}
```

Comment: No, No me funciona, sigue igual ;(